# Create an object with properties,

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript...
I trying to create an object- "Flower".
Every Flower has it properties: price,color,height...

Can somebody give me an idea how to build it?

Create an object and then change his properties?

:-)

Comment: A normal JavaScript object? You won't need jQuery for that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
flower= {
 price : function() { 
     console.log('Price is 78 $'); 
 },
 color: 'red',
 height : 23
};

flower.price();
flower.height ;
```

Comment: Good for singleton objects.

Answer (score 12):

Have an object, where you can also bind functions to. The following should be used if you want to have multiple Flower objects, because you can easily create new Flowers and they will all have the functions you have added:

```
function Flower(price, color, height){
    this.price = price;
    this.color= color;
    this.height= height;

    this.myfunction = function()
    {
        alert(this.color);
    }
}

var fl = new Flower(12, "green", 65);
fl.color = "new color");

alert(fl.color);
fl.myfunction();
```

If you want to have a sort of array just use an object literal, but you need to set the properties and functions for each Object you create.

```
var flower = { price : 12, 
               color : "green",
               myfunction : function(){
                   alert(this.price);
               }
};
flower.price = 20;
alert(flower.price);
alert(flower.myfunction());
```

Comment: Have updated my post, tried out to have a function inside the JSON format, and the `this` object refers to the element, so you can use both if you want to start using functions.

Answer (score 5):

```
var flower = {"height" : 18.3, "price":10.0, "color":"blue"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pattern to create object with public/private section(s)

```
var MyObj = function()
{
    // private section
    var privateColor = 'red';

    function privateMethod()
    {
        console.log('privateMethod. The color is: ', privateColor);
    }

    // The public section
    return
    {
        publicColor : 'blue',
        publicMehtod: function()
        {
            // See the diffrent usage to 'this' keyword
            console.log('publicMehtod. publicColor:', this.publicColor, ', Private color: ', privateColor);
        },
        setPrivateColor: function(newColor)
        {
            // No need for this
            privateColor = newColor;
        },
        debug: function()
        {
            this.publicMehtod();
        }
    };
}

var obj1 = new MyObj();
obj1.publicMehtod();
obj1.setPrivateColor('Yellow');
obj1.publicMehtod();

var obj2 = new MyObj();
obj2.publicMehtod();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var flower = {"propertyName1": propertyValue1, "propertyName2": propertyValue};
```

To retrieve the values:

```
var price = flower.price;
```

To change property values:

```
flower.price = newPrice;
```