# How can I return two parameters from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
function getPk(entity) {
    var store = window.localStorage;
    switch (entity) {
        case "City":
            if (store.getItem('AccountID')) {
                // Need to return both of the below pieces of information
                return store.getItem('AccountID') + "04" + "000";
                return "CityTable";

            } else {
                paramOnFailure("Please reselect"); 
                return false;
            }
            break;
```

The problem is I need to be able to call this function and return two strings. Here I show two return statements but I know I cannot do that.

Is there a clean way I can return two strings to the function that calls my getPk(entity) function?

If possible can you give an example also of how I can read what is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return them as either an array, or within an object.

```
return [store.getItem('AccountID') + "04" + "000", "CityTable"];
```

or

```
return { accountID: store.getItem('AccountID') + "04" + "000", table: "CityTable" };
```

Comment: I'm sorry but then how do I read the array? Can you give an example of the calling function and what comes back. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can only return a single value from a function in JavaScript, but that value can be a structure that contains multiple values internally, such as an array:

```
return [store.getItem('AccountID') + "04" + "000", "CityTable"];
```

Just make sure that the functions which call this know about the conventions you're using for your return value.

Comment: But can you show me how the calling function would read this. I'm sorry but my knowledge of javascript is very basic.

Comment: `var x = getPk(entity);`, then refer to `x[0]` and `x[1]` to refer to the two values you returned.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript and like almost every languages, It is impossible to return more than one value.

However, you can return a custom object containing all the values you want to return.

See the following link to find how to create an object.
[Create an object with properties,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224680/create-an-object-with-properties)