# Instantiating a javascript object and populating its properties in a single line

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can do all of this in a constructor?

```
  obj = new Object();
  obj.city = "A";
  obj.town = "B";
```

Comment: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: Yes, of course.  You can see some usage here:  [Previously answered question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an object with properties,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224680/create-an-object-with-properties)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why don't you just do it this way:

```
var obj = {"city": "A", "town": "B"};
```

Comment: and the quotes around city and town are optional.

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

```
var obj = {
    city: "a",
    town: "b"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function MyObject(params) {
    // Your constructor
    this.init(params);
}

MyObject.prototype = {
    init: function(params) {
        // Your code called by constructor
    }
}

var objectInstance = new MyObject(params);
```

This would be the prototype way, which i prefere over plain object literals when i need more then one instance of the object.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var obj = {
    city : "A",
    town : "B"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.talk = function() {
        alert( this.name + " say meeow!" )
    }
} 

cat1 = new cat("felix")
cat1.talk() //alerts "felix says meeow!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your custom constructor :

```
function myObject(c,t) {
    this.city = c;
    this.town = t;
}

var obj = new myObject("A","B");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function MyObject(city, town) {
  this.city = city;
  this.town = town;
}

MyObject.prototype.print = function() {
  alert(city + " " + town);
}

obj = new MyObject("myCity", "myTown");
obj.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not complicate things. Here is a simplest way of defining a constructor.

```
var Cont = function(city, town) {
           this.city = city;
           this.town = town;
          }

var Obj = new Cont('A', 'B');
```

Comment: This would lead to private only methods in your class. By using prototype, you can define methods which are accessible from outside of your class. If you need private methods, you can still define them within the constructor function.

Comment: This will not lead to private methods. Please read http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: From your link: "Private methods are inner functions of the constructor." This is basically what you would end up with, if you would declare functions in your definition.