# Is there a way to write javascript object array in one line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Is there a way to write this in one line?

```
  var data = {};
  data["limit"] = [1, 0]; 
  data["where"] = [0]; 
  data["order"] = [];
  data["display"] = [0];
```

Something like

```
var data = {["limit"][1,0],["where"][0]...}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: [Instantiating a javascript object and populating its properties in a single line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777357/instantiating-a-javascript-object-and-populating-its-properties-in-a-single-line)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript objects can be written in a [one-liner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) like this:

```
var data = {limit: [1, 0], where: [0], order: [], display: [0]};
```

Comment: It may be useful to include an explanation as to what exactly this is, perhaps a useful link, etc.

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 5):

You can use an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) (the quotes around property names are in fact optional):

```
var data = {
  'limit': [1,0],
  'where': [0],
  'order': [],
  'display': [0]
};
```

Comment: @vihan1086: Everything in Javascript can be made one line by just stripping away the line breaks…

Comment: @vihan1086 I interpret "one line" (and "one-liner") to mean one *statement*, not one physical line. Otherwise for any language which does not use a newline as a delimiter (C family, Java, JavaScript, etc), the entire program can technically be written as one line. As can the original code in the question, frankly!

Answer (score 0):

My json skills are minimal, but it should be

```
{"limit":[1,0], "where":[0], "order":[], "display":[0]}
```

or some permutation of that (order in an object isn't meaningful as far as I know).